# How to iterate over items in a comma-separated list in ConTeXt?

Tags: lists, context, loops

I have a very simple list like this:

```
cat, fish, dog, rabbit
```

(this is is comma-separated, but it is fine if the data is stored in some other way, but it needs to allow for any number of items to be added to the list)

I want to store the list somewhere. Then a simple macro, such as `\droptext` is placed in the document. The first time it is displayed, it prints "cat", the second time, "fish", etc. The fifth and ninth time it returns to "cat", repeating the loop.

```
\starttext
    \define\mylist{cat, fish, dog, rabbit}

    The \droptext\ is a nice animal. So is the \droptext.
    Once upon a time, a \droptext\ came to the garden
    and ate a \droptext. Everyone was so angry
    but then the \droptext came by and brought everyone
    a \droptext.

\stoptext
```

That would print on the page:

```
The cat is a nice animal. So is the fish.
Once upon a time, a dog came to the garden
and ate a rabbit. Everyone was so angry
but then the cat came by and brought everyone
a fish.
```

- I tried the `\doloop` command, as from the description seems like it might do this, but the document couldn't even compile when that command was added.

Is there a way to print items from a list, each time a macro appears in the document, iterating through the items, in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** My old answer only works with ConTeXt LMTX. There's an alternative which work with both LMTX and MkIV.

```
\startluacode

userdata = userdata or {}
userdata.my_lists = {}

interfaces.implement{
    name = "registercyclelist",
    public = true,
    arguments = {"string", "string"},
    actions = {
        function (name, t)
            userdata.my_lists[name] = utilities.parsers.settings_to_array(t)
        end
    }
}

interfaces.implement{
    name = "usecyclelist",
    public = true,
    arguments = {"string"},
    actions = {
        function (name)
            local first = userdata.my_lists[name][1]
            table.remove(userdata.my_lists[name], 1)
            table.insert(userdata.my_lists[name], first)
            return first 
        end,
        context
    }
}

\stopluacode

%Notice the braces 
\registercyclelist{firstlist}{cat, fish, dog, rabbit}
\def\droptext{\usecyclelist{firstlist}}

\starttext

The \droptext\ is a nice animal. So is the \droptext.
Once upon a time, a \droptext\ came to the garden
and ate a \droptext. Everyone was so angry
but then the \droptext\ came by and brought everyone
a \droptext.

\stoptext
```

Comment: When I compile just this without any changes, it prints the error "[ctxlua]:23: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')"

Comment: Yeah, I see. I've used a feature not available in LuaTeX. Let me edit my answer

Comment: @Village See updated answer.

Comment: I didn't realize there was another version of ConTeXt. I thought I had the latest version, and in fact, updated it last week.

Comment: @Village Check your PDF info. If it refers to LuaTeX 1.something (mine is LuaTeX-1.13) it is ConTeXt MkIV (TeX Live is in 1.12, I think); if it refers to LuaTeX 2.something (mine is LuaTeX-2.08) it is ConTeXt LMTX.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior that you want is exactly how context treats footnote markers etc in the conversion built in conversion sets. See [this wiki page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/convertnumber) but built in conversion set demo. These conversion sets are used to indicate footnotes markers in pages (in some article styles).

So, here is a solution which achieves the desired effect by piggybacking on the counter mechanism:

```
\defineconversion[animal][cat,fish,dog,rabbit]
\definecounter[myanimals][numberconversion=animal]

\define\droptext{\incrementcounter[myanimals]\convertedcounter[myanimals]}
```

Basically, define a new conversion called `animal`, which specifies the conversion set that you want. Then define a counter called `myanimal`, with the numberconversion equal to `animal`. Then, `droptext` simply increments the counter and displays its "converted value". ConTeXt takes care of traversing the list internally.